# Commutative diagrams side by side have different sizes

Tags: commutative-diagrams

Within the statement of a theorem, I have two commutative diagrams. I am trying to use `pb-diagram` to create them and I would like them to be side by side. Unfortunately the size of the commutative diagrams seem to depend on the size of the symbols at the nodes, and the two commutative diagrams come out to be different sizes. Is there any way to fix this?

Here is the code I have right now:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[arrow,matrix,curve,cmtip,ps]{xy}
\usepackage{pb-diagram} 
\usepackage{pb-xy}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{diagram}
\node{\mathcal{C}_R}\arrow{e,t}{P}\arrow{s,l,J}{\Psi}\node {\mathcal{C}_R}\arrow{s,l,J}{\Psi}\\
\node{\widehat{\mathcal{C}}_R}\arrow{e,t}{E(P)}\node{\widehat{\mathcal{C}}_R}
\end{diagram}\hspace{40pt}
\begin{diagram}
\node{\mathcal{C}_{R,\,\operatorname{top}}}\arrow{e,t}{P}\arrow{s,l,J}{\Psi}\node {\mathcal{C}_{R,\,\operatorname{top}}}\arrow{s,l,J}{\Psi}\\
\node{\widehat{\mathcal{C}}_{R,\,\operatorname{top}}}\arrow{e,t}{E(P)}\node{\widehat{\mathcal{C}}_{R,\,\operatorname{top}}}
\end{diagram}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

and here is the result of compiling:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of the site

Comment: Could you provide the contents of a complete compilable `.tex` file, starting with `\documentclass`? In particular, I'm wondering which package you're loading to get the `diagram` environment.

Comment: @JohnWickerson I just added those details, I really should have done so at the outset, sorry!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know how to do with `pb-diagram`, which is a very old package. A more modern one, and more powerful too, is `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{pb-diagram}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}
\newcommand{\Chat}{\hat{\C}}
\renewcommand{\top}{\mathrm{top}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}
\C_R \arrow{r}{P} \arrow[hookrightarrow,swap]{d}{\Psi} &
\C_R \arrow[hookrightarrow,swap]{d}{\Psi}\\
\Chat_R \arrow{r}{E(P)} & \Chat_R
\end{tikzcd}\hspace{40pt}%
\begin{tikzcd}
\C_{R\smash{,\,\top}} \arrow{r}{P} \arrow[hookrightarrow,swap]{d}{\Psi} &
\C_{R\smash{,\,\top}} \arrow[hookrightarrow,swap]{d}{\Psi}\\
\Chat_{R\smash{,\,\top}} \arrow{r}{E(P)} & \Chat_{R\smash{,\,\top}}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

It's necessary to "smash" the comma and the word "top", because they have descenders that would make the second diagram a bit larger.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As you are using [xy-pic](http://www.tug.org/applications/Xy-pic/), it can alone draw commutative diagrams.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
& \mathcal{C}_R \ar@{^{(}->}[d]_{\Psi} \ar[r]^P & \mathcal{C}_R \ar@{^{(}->}[d]_{\Psi}\\ 
& \widehat{\mathcal{C}}_R \ar[r]^{E(P)} & \widehat{\mathcal{C}}_R }

\xymatrix{
& \mathcal{C}_{R,\,\mathrm{top}} \ar@{^{(}->}[d]_{\Psi} \ar[r]^P 
& \mathcal{C}_{R,\,\mathrm{top}} \ar@{^{(}->}[d]_{\Psi} \\ 
& \widehat{\mathcal{C}}_{R,\,\mathrm{top}} \ar[r]^{E(P)} 
& \widehat{\mathcal{C}}_{R,\,\mathrm{top}} }
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

> [image]